# Sumar registros con un status especifico con MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT *, SUM(psb_produc)/SUM(psb_rate) AS TotalProd
FROM psb_smt.psb_produccion A
LEFT JOIN 
    psb_smt.psb_info B ON A.id_psbinfo = B.id
WHERE linea='Linea 05' AND B.DateTime>='2020-01-27 06:40:00' AND B.EndDate<='2020-01-28 06:39:00' AND A.statusdtp=0
```

La duda es la siguiente: de que manera puedo seguir haciendo la suma y mostrando un resultado de los registros que tengan el statusdtp=1, el problema esta en que si en el registro tiene statusdtp=0 ya no me muestra nada y yo quiero seguir obteniendo la suma solamente que me ignore ese registro para que no lo sume.

Comment: En el WHERE donde dices `AND A.statusdtp=0`no deberías tener `AND A.statusdtp=1` si tal como dices solo quieres la suma cuando `statusdtp=1`

Answer (score 2):

Para mostrar los registros con statusdtp = 0 y 1 podrías hacer un **IN** (0,1) y para que solo sume los registros que posean statusdtp = 1 un condicional con **WHEN**.

La query te quedaría de la siguiente forma y traería los registros que posean statusdtp 0 y 1 pero solo sumaría los statusdtp = 1.

```
SELECT *, 
  CASE WHEN A.statustdp = 1
   THEN SUM(psb_produc)/SUM(psb_rate)
   ELSE ''
  END AS TotalProd
FROM psb_smt.psb_produccion A
LEFT JOIN psb_smt.psb_info B 
   ON A.id_psbinfo = B.id
WHERE linea='Linea 05' 
  AND B.DateTime>='2020-01-27 06:40:00' 
  AND B.EndDate<='2020-01-28 06:39:00' 
  AND A.statusdtp IN (0,1)
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo en cuenta que lo que estás describiendo es únicamente sumar aquellos en los que statusdtp es igual a 1, creo que lo que buscas es esto (únicamente sustituye `A.statusdtp=0` por `A.statusdtp=1` en el WHERE):

```sql
SELECT *, SUM(psb_produc)/SUM(psb_rate) AS TotalProd
    FROM psb_smt.psb_produccion A
LEFT JOIN
    psb_smt.psb_info B ON A.id_psbinfo = B.id
WHERE linea='Linea 05' AND B.DateTime>='2020-01-27 06:40:00' AND B.EndDate<='2020-01-28 06:39:00' AND A.statusdtp=1
```